# command line to access PingFederate Console

Tags: curl, command-line, command-prompt, pingfederate

We have some issues to access PingFederate Console or REST API.

Is it possible to access PingFederate using commandline.

If yes which commands we can use to perform operations.

Comment: What's your issue with the REST API?

Comment: to use REST API and PIngFederateConsole, user needs to be created under user management tab which is disabled.

Comment: This is not true. This indicates that the server authentication is being managed elsewhere (like in PingOne or LDAP), and so authentication should proceed accordingly.

Comment: Andrew K. is correct. I would highly recommend reviewing your admin authentication configuration: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/index.shtml#adminGuide/concept/alternativeConsoleAuthentication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ability to access PingFederate administrative functions outside the REST API or the Administration UI.

Comment: so, commandline can only be used to shut down and start up PingFederate?